# weight painting in blender displaying black color

Tags: weight-painting

While weight painting the mesh only shows two colors Red and black in solid mode. It is not showing intermediate values like green and blue. if I switch to wireframe mode the weight colors are displaying correctly. How to rectify this? I am using blender ver 2.83[image: Wire frame mode displaying color colors]  [image: normal solid mode displaying black color]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Perhaps the shading of the viewport is shaded to the maximum. Reduce from 1.0 to .25. If you want you can also set Lighting for FLAT.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It helped. changed the color from material to single.